# How to sort a list in order of weekdays in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of tuples witch looks like this:

```
lst = [(2921, 'string', 1, 1, 7), (2922, 'string', 2, 1, 1), (2923, 'string', 3, 1, 4),
        (2924, 'string', 4, 2, 2), (2925, 'string', 5, 2, 3), (2926, 'string', 6, 2, 5),
        (2927, 'string', 7, 2, 3), (2928, 'string', 8, 3, 4), (2929, 'string', 9, 3, 4),
        (2930, 'string', 10, 3, 5), (2931, 'string', 11, 3, 5), (2932, 'string', 12, 4, 6),
        (2933, 'string', 13, 4, 6), (2934, 'string', 14, 4, 7), (2935, 'string', 15, 7, 1),
        (2936, 'string', 16, 5, 1), (2937, 'string', 17, 5, 2)]
```

The last element (fifth item) in each tuple corresponds to the day of the week numbered 1 thru 7.

I would to sort the list so that the resulting tuples cycle through the days of the week in ascending order as follows:

1. Select the first tuple with 1, then first with 2, until 7 (skip number if no tuple with that number)
2. Select the second tuple with 2, then the second with 3, until reach 7 again.
3. Continue this cycling process (i.e. of first, second, third, etc.) until out of tuples.

Desired Output:

```
(2922, 'string', 2, 1, 1)
(2924, 'string', 4, 2, 2)
(2925, 'string', 5, 2, 3)
(2923, 'string', 3, 1, 4)
(2926, 'string', 6, 2, 5)
(2932, 'string', 12, 4, 6)
(2921, 'string', 1, 1, 7)
(2935, 'string', 15, 7, 1)
(2937, 'string', 17, 5, 2)
(2927, 'string', 7, 2, 3)
(2928, 'string', 8, 3, 4)
(2930, 'string', 10, 3, 5)
(2933, 'string', 13, 4, 6)
(2934, 'string', 14, 4, 7)
(2936, 'string', 16, 5, 1)
(2929, 'string', 9, 3, 4)
(2931, 'string', 11, 3, 5)
```

I tried to do it with custom sort function, but it is not working as I need:

```
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x[4], days.index))

for i in sorted_list:
    print(i)
```

Maybe 'sorting' isn’t actually the right term for it.. anyway I want to order the list elements based on the fifth element of the tuples. And I want to order them like weekdays: from Monday to Sunday and after Sunday comes Monday again. So, 1 to 7 and then again 1 to 7. Like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2 ...

not 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 ...

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "days.index" in your lambda (.index without argument)?
2. Why you need it in the first place. You "days" list has sorted values.

Comment: Do not name your list 'list'. That should be a reserved word and is a source of confusion.
As for the sorting - you have to be clear about what you want. Suppose you have a list of weekdays which is [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,3,2]. What output do you expect?

Comment: Your desired output is not sorted - why `(2935, 'string', 15, 7, 1)`, comes after `(2921, 'string', 1, 1, 7)` and so on...

Comment: You asked the almost the same exact thing about 12h ago. Instead of reposting closed question, try to read through [ask] and edit it into shape.  "but it is not working as I need" is not enough as problem description

Comment: @PaulUheet check out solution and let me know any other issue and please follow all necessary guideline to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dict` object is one of the data-structure to solve this problem. **Check out this code:**

```
list_ = [(2921, 'string', 1, 1, 7), (2922, 'string', 2, 1, 1), (2923, 'string', 3, 1, 4),
        (2924, 'string', 4, 2, 2), (2925, 'string', 5, 2, 3), (2926, 'string', 6, 2, 5),
        (2927, 'string', 7, 2, 3), (2928, 'string', 8, 3, 4), (2929, 'string', 9, 3, 4),
        (2930, 'string', 10, 3, 5), (2931, 'string', 11, 3, 5), (2932, 'string', 12, 4, 6),
        (2933, 'string', 13, 4, 6), (2934, 'string', 14, 4, 7), (2935, 'string', 15, 7, 1),
        (2936, 'string', 16, 5, 1), (2937, 'string', 17, 5, 2)]


days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

dict_sort_ = {f'{i}':[j for j in list_ if j[-1] == i] for i in days}

condn = True
day = 1
while  condn:
    try:    
        print(dict_sort_[str(day)][0])
        dict_sort_[str(day)].pop(0)
        if day >= 7:
            day %= 7
    except:
        continue
    finally:
        day += 1
    if all([True if len(dict_sort_[i])==0 else False for i in dict_sort_]):
        condn = False
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(2922, 'string', 2, 1, 1)
(2924, 'string', 4, 2, 2)
(2925, 'string', 5, 2, 3)
(2923, 'string', 3, 1, 4)
(2926, 'string', 6, 2, 5)
(2932, 'string', 12, 4, 6)
(2921, 'string', 1, 1, 7)
(2935, 'string', 15, 7, 1)
(2937, 'string', 17, 5, 2)
(2927, 'string', 7, 2, 3)
(2928, 'string', 8, 3, 4)
(2930, 'string', 10, 3, 5)
(2933, 'string', 13, 4, 6)
(2934, 'string', 14, 4, 7)
(2936, 'string', 16, 5, 1)
(2929, 'string', 9, 3, 4)
(2931, 'string', 11, 3, 5)
```

Comment: last line of problem give all point to work upon I am quoting it "Like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2 ..."

Comment: Which means user want to iterate form Monday to Sunday in such a way that no two Days should come together

Comment: Yes, Exploore X, you are right, this is exactly what I want. Thank you! And sorry if the question was not clear enough. I wonder, is this the most efficient way to do it? If the list has thousands of items it could be quite slow ..

Comment: @PaulUheet now I updated my solution, previously it contain some wrong logic, now this is finally  corrected.

Comment: @PaulUheet also let me know if you have any issue related to this also